# Creating a generic version of a function that groups elements of a list that satisfy certain certain conditions

Tags: scala, list

I've a function that groups a `List` of `Person`s if their first names are same AND and they are adjacent to each other in the list.

```
  case class Person(first:String,last:String,age:Int) 

  @annotation.tailrec
  def groupPersons(persons: List[Person], results: List[List[Person]] = Nil): List[List[Person]] = persons match {
    case Nil => results.reverse
    case persons => groupPersons(persons.dropWhile(_.first == persons.head.first), persons.takeWhile(_.first == persons.head.first) :: results)
  }
```

I would like to create a generic version of this function that works other types as well and takes in a function that is passed to `dropWhile` and `takeWhile`.

Something like:

```
  def group(p: List[P], results: List[List[P]] = Nil, f: (P,P) => Boolean): List[List[P]] = {
    p match {
      case Nil => results.reverse
      case p => group(p.dropWhile(f), p.takeWhile(f) :: results, f)
    }
  }
```

Cannot make the above to work? Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most of the way there. Adding a type parameter to `group` fixes one problem. Your other problem is that `dropWhile` and `takeWhile` takas a predicate (`P=> Boolean`), but you want to use an `f` that takes two parameters. We can fix this by currying  `f` and partially applying. Finally, `span` will be slightly more efficient than your `takeWhile`/`dropWhile`

```
  def group[P](p: List[P], 
               results: List[List[P]] = Nil, 
               f: (P,P) => Boolean): List[List[P]] = {
   p match {
     case Nil => results.reverse

     case p => {
       val g = f.curried(p.head)
       val (matching, rest) = p.span(g)
       group(rest, matching :: results, f)
     }
   }
} 

val xs = List(Person("John", "Doe", 42), Person("Jane", "Smith", 50), 
              Person("Jane", "Piper", 52), Person("Mary", "Morse", 52))

def matchFirstName(a:Person,b:Person) = a.first == b.first

group(xs, Nil, matchFirstName) 
//> res0: List[List[exprs.exprs.Person]] = List(List(Person(John,Doe,42)), List(
//| Person(Jane,Smith,50), Person(Jane,Piper,52)), List(Person(Mary,Morse,52)))
```

Comment: you can curry function like this: `def test(f: (String, Boolean) => String) = f.curried`

Comment: @Alexlv,Yes, that's neater. Updated

Comment: Still outer list cannot be properly adjacent, cause, from your example, what if first Jane's age is 40, which is less then Johns, then you need to split the group.

Comment: @Alexlv - @Paul's answer is correct. I just need to group elements by only one field whenever they are adjacent. In this case `first`. If `xs = List(Person("John", "Doe", 42), Person("Jane", "Smith", 50), Person("Mary", "Morse", 52)), Person("Jane", "Piper", 52))` then the result will be `List(List(Person(John,Doe,42)), List(Person(Jane,Smith,50)), List(Person(Mary,Morse,52)), List(Person(Jane,Piper,52)))`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this want you need, but there is a better way:

```
case class Person(first:String,last:String,age:Int)
val xs = List(Person("John", "Doe", 42), Person("Jane", "Smith", 50), Person("Jane", "Piper", 52), Person("Mary", "Morse", 52))
```

There is a function `groupBy`:

```
scala> xs.groupBy(_.first)
res0: Map[String,List[Person]] = 
  Map(Jane -> List(Person(Jane,Smith,50), Person(Jane,Piper,52)), 
      Mary -> List(Person(Mary,Morse,52)), 
      John -> List(Person(John,Doe,42)))
```

you can convert to into a List: `xs.groupBy(_.first).toList` and then continue process your data.

Thanks to @Paul, i haven't noted the requirement to be "adjacent to each other". It looks to me like a simple sort application, i.e `sortWith` function which takes a function lt: `(A, A) => Boolean` just like your `f` parameter.

Comment: That isn't what the OP asked for (although it's the same for my example). I think you overlooked "AND and they are adjacent to each other in the list."

Comment: @Paul adjacent is to broad for me, i just showed that his logic can be expressed in terms of `groupBy` function. As for adjacent, i guess that can be done with `sortWith`

Comment: The OP can clarify but it seems clear the elements of each group must be next two each other in the original list. I don't see how `sortWith` helps much there.